# SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting this error messages `SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections`, I'm using pdo adapter. Do I need to close connection? And how I do that?

Answer (score 20):

In your my.conf file (usually located in /etc) find the line that says:

```
[mysqld]
```

And somewhere below that set

```
max_connections=500
```

Or whatever numeric value you need.

More information here: [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual: Too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html).

Comment: For those had trouble finding `my.conf` file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27325487/515585

Comment: Small typo: the correct syntax is `max_connections=500`, not `max-connections=500` as originally stated in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need change your `my.cnf` file.

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=250
```

Upper the value.

Comment: The string "set-variable=" is no longer needed since MySQL 5.x, so the other answer provided by Camden S. is correct.

Comment: But why does this happen? Is it because the connections aren't closed like asked in the question?

Answer (score 12):

The root cause for this error for me was a full hard drive. Keep that in mind as a possibility.

Comment: My root cause was also a full hard drive.

Answer (score 8):

In your mysql my must to run this:

```
Set Global max_connections=2000
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I executed

Comment: That works, but lasts only until you restart your MySQL server. So, a good way to bridge that time if you don't want to restart it immediately, but you also have edit `my.cnf` as shown in the other answers to make this change permanent.