# Symfony2 unit testing: PDOException: SQLSTATE[00000] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, pdo

when I run unit tests for my application, first tests are successful, then around 100, tests start to fail, due to PDOException (Too many connections). I have already searched about this problem, but was not able to solve it.

My config is as follows:

```
<phpunit
        backupGlobals               = "false"
        backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
        colors                      = "true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
        processIsolation            = "false"
        stopOnFailure               = "false"
        syntaxCheck                 = "false"
        bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >
```

If I change processIsolation to "true", all tests generate an error (E):

```
Caused by ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 79 bytes
```

For that I tried setting "detect_unicode = Off" inside php.ini file.

If I run tests in smaller batches, like with "--group something", all tests are successful.

Can someone help me solve the issue when running all the tests at once? I really want to get rid of the PDOException.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the maximum number of concurrent connections in your DB server.

If you're using MySQL, edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set the `max_connections` parameter to the number of concurrent connections you need. Then restart the MySQL server.

Keep in mind: In theory, the physical limits are very high. But if your queries cause a high CPU load or memory consumption, your DB server could eat up the resources required for other processes. This means, you could run out of memory, or your system can become overloaded.

Comment: Seems to work! Thanks! For now maybe this is a temporary solution, I hope I don't get the errors when I add more tests.

Comment: Don't worry. ;) If you're not loading MBs of data per query, or have some super-weird joins, your MySQL server can handle several thousands of concurrent requests on a modern machine.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are having the same issue, here is more specific steps to config the `my.cnf` file. 
If you are sure you are on the right `my.cnf` file, put `max_connections = 500` (default is 151) to `[mysqld]` section in the `my.cnf`. Don't put it in the `[client]` section.

To make sure you are on the right `my.cnf`, if you have multiple mysqld installed from Homebrew or XAMMPP, find the right `mysqld`, for XAMMPP using `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"` and you will get something like this:

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/xampp/my.cnf /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

Normally it's at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`.